# Show that $f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+nx^{2})n^{\alpha}}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$, if $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, real-numbers

Consider the function defined by $$f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+nx^{2})n^{\alpha}}.$$

I have showed that, by Weierstrass M-test, when $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$, the series converges uniformly to $f$ on $[\epsilon, R]$ for $\epsilon, R>0$ arbitrarily fixed. Hence, $f(x)$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ for $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$.

The second part of this exercise asks me to prove that

> For $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$, $$f(x)\longrightarrow 0\ \text{as}\ x\rightarrow 0.$$

Since I only showed that $f(x)$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$, not at $x=0$, I cannot use $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=f(0).$

What alternative do I have? I tried to show that the series converges uniformly on $[-\epsilon, \epsilon]$ so that taking $\epsilon\searrow 0$, we can conclude that $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$. However I failed since the bound in M-test cannot be established..

Is there any other way to approach this exercise? Thank you!

**Edit 1:**

Okay I figured it out. It turned out that the proof is really complicated.  Note that there is no way to prove the uniform convergence in either $[0,\epsilon]$ or $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$. The second one cannot give you the desired $M_{n}$ in Weierstrass $M-$test. The first one give you $M_{n}=\frac{\epsilon}{2^{\alpha}}$ but $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$ so the series diverges.

Give me several minutes so that I can post the solution in the answer my post section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note for $x\ge 0$, we have from the AM-GM inequality

$$\left|\frac{x}{(1+nx^2)n^\alpha}\right|\le \frac{1}{2n^{\alpha+1/2}}$$

Inasmuch as for $\alpha>1/2$, $\sum_{n=1}\frac1{n^{\alpha+1/2}}<\infty$, we can apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem (note that we also have uniform convergence for $x\in [0,\infty)$) to find

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{(1+nx^2)n^\alpha}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{(1+nx^2)n^\alpha}0$$

Now, repeat for the case $x\le 0$.

Comment: I don't really know this inequality. Thank you for this great answer!

Comment: I just wikipedia the AM-GM inequality, but cannot figure out how you obtained the inequality in your post. Would you mind elaborating a little?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Note that $x+y\ge 2\sqrt{xy}$ is equivalent to $(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2\ge 0$ which is true for all $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge0$.  Now, let $x=1$ and $y=nx^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Define $g(x,t):=\frac{x}{(1+tx^{2})t^{\alpha}}$ for $x\in (0,\infty)$ fixed and $t=1,2,3,\cdots$. Note that $g(x,t)$ is decreasing in $t$, and thus for $t\in [n,n+1]$, $n=1,2,3,\cdots$, using the monotonicity of integral, we have $$g(x,n+1)=g(x,n+1)\int_{n}^{n+1}1dt=\int_{n}^{n+1}g(x,n+1)dt\leq \int_{n}^{n+1}g(x,t)dt\leq\int_{n}^{n+1}g(x,n)dt=g(x,n).$$

Therefore, we have $$\dfrac{x}{(1+(n+1)x^{2})(n+1)^{\alpha}}\leq \int_{n}^{n+1}g(x,t)dt\leq\dfrac{x}{(1+nx^{2})n^{\alpha}}.$$ Summing oer $n=1,2,\cdots,$ we have $$f(x)-\dfrac{x}{1+x^{2}}\leq \int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x}{(1+tx^{2})t^{\alpha}}dt\leq f(x).$$

Taking $x\rightarrow 0$, we see that $\frac{x}{1+x^{2}}\longrightarrow 0$, hence we have $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x}{(1+tx^{2})t^{\alpha}}dt\leq\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)\leq \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x}{(1+tx^{2})t^{\alpha}}dt.$$

Hence, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)= \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x}{(1+tx^{2})t^{\alpha}}dt.$$

To evaluate the RHS, replace $u:=\sqrt{t}$ (this may take a while to find), so that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x}{(1+tx^{2})t^{\alpha}}dt=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}2\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x}{(1+u^{2}x^{2})u^{2\alpha-1}}du.$$ But not that $$\Big|\dfrac{x}{(1+u^{2}x^{2})u^{2\alpha-1}}\Big|\leq x^{-1}u^{-2\alpha-1}$$ which satisfies $\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{-1}u^{-2\alpha-1}du<\infty.$

Therefore, it follows from dominated convergence theorem that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}2\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x}{(1+u^{2}x^{2})u^{2\alpha-1}}du= 2\int_{1}^{\infty}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{x}{(1+u^{2}x^{2})u^{2\alpha-1}}du=0.$$

Thus, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=0.$

---

Please let me know if the proof has typos or mistakes. I omit several computations since it takes time to write down.

Comment: This doesn't quite work.  Your bounding function depends on $\frac1x$.  To apply the DCT, the bounding function must be independent of $x$.

Comment: @MarkViola yes you are right. $x$ now is the index. Thanks!